# How to access local component variable from a callback in vue?

Tags: vue.js, callback, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

I am trying to set my components variable using an api rest command.  I wanted to handle all responses through a function in its own file called handleResponse() which is below.

```
// api/tools/index.js
function handleResponse (promise, cb, cbError) {
  var cbErrorRun = (cbError && typeof cb === "function") 

  promise.then(function (response) {
    if (!response.error) {
      cb(response)
    }
    else if (cbErrorRun) {
      cbError(response)
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
    if (cbErrorRun) {
      var responseError = {
        "status": 404,
        "error": true,
        "message": error.toString()
      }
      cbError(responseError)
    }
  })
}
export {handleResponse}
```

In my component file I have this

```
.... More above....
<script>
import { fetchStock } from '@/api/stock'    

  export default {

    data () {
      return {
        stock: {},
        tabs: [
          {
            title: 'Info',
            id: 'info'
          },
          {
            title: 'Listings',
            id: 'listings'
          },
          {
            title: 'Company',
            id: 'company'
          }
        ],
      }
    },
    validate ({params}) {
      return /^\d+$/.test(params.id)
    },
    created: function() {
      var params = {'id': this.$route.params.stockId}
      //this.$route.params.stockId}
      fetchStock(
        params,
        function(response) { //on successful data retrieval
          this.stock = response.data.payload // payload = {'name': test123}
          console.log(response)
        },
        function(responseError) { //on error
          console.log(responseError)
        }
      )
    }
  }
</script>
```

The current code gives me this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'stock' of undefinedAc".  I think this happens because I no longer have access to 'this' within the callback I pass in the fetchStock function.  How would I fix this without changing the current handleResponse layout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this trick

```
  created: function() {
      var params = {'id': this.$route.params.stockId}
      //this.$route.params.stockId}
      var self = this;
      fetchStock(
        params,
        function(response) { //on successful data retrieval
          self.stock = response.data.payload // payload = {'name': test123}
          console.log(response)
        },
        function(responseError) { //on error
          console.log(responseError)
        }
      )
    }
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I have been trying everything and tearing my hair.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an arrow function for you callback since arrow functions maintain and use the `this` of their containing scope:

```js
created: function() {
      var params = {'id': this.$route.params.stockId}
      //this.$route.params.stockId}

      fetchStock(
        params,
        (response) => { //on successful data retrieval
          self.stock = response.data.payload // payload = {'name': test123}
          console.log(response)
        },
        (responseError) => { //on error
          console.log(responseError)
        }
      )
    }
```

Or you can assign `const vm = this` n the beginning of your method before the callbacks like so.

> vm stands for "View Model"

```js
  created: function() {
      var params = {'id': this.$route.params.stockId}
      //this.$route.params.stockId}
      const vm = this;
      fetchStock(
        params,
        function(response) { //on successful data retrieval
          self.stock = response.data.payload // payload = {'name': test123}
          console.log(response)
        },
        function(responseError) { //on error
          console.log(responseError)
        }
      )
    }
```

> I advise using the `const` as opposed to `var` in the `vm` declaration to make it obvious the value of `vm` is a constant.